# 1 Column find and replace

Tags: excel, vba

Column N contains the following information:

```
Doe, Jane
Doe, John
Doe, Jr., Johnny
```

I am using the following Excel VB for Applications code:

```
Columns("N").Replace What:=", Jr.,", _
                          Replacement:=" Jr.,", _
                          LookAt:=xlpPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=False, _
                          MatchCase:=True, _
                          SearchFormat:=False, _
                          ReplaceFormat:=False
```

It works fine as long there is a name that contains ", Jr.,".  If the columns does not contain this value, I receive Run-time error "9": subscript out of range.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: You could use `Column("N").Find` before you blindly perform a replace?

Comment: It shouldn't matter. There must be something else that is causing the error. Maybe `xlPart` instead of `xlpPart`.

Answer (score 1):

The absence of something to replace should not throw an error. The code *should* be able to be run against a completely blank column.

```
With ActiveSheet
    With .Columns("N")
        .Replace What:=", Jr.,", Replacement:=" Jr.,", LookAt:=xlPart
    End With
End With
```

Note that your original sample contained `xlpPart` in place of `xlPart`.

Comment: I am sorry, I reviewed the logic again, and I changed it as follows:

Comment: Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("N").Replace _
                        What:=", Jr.,", _
                        Replacement:=" Jr.,", _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        MatchCase:=True